# What chart type do I need for a wave line

Tags: c#, charts, trigonometry

What chart type do I need for a wave line like the sinus / cosinus? I'm using the default chart in windows forms.

```
chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
```

Is this the right chart type for this?

Also how do I display radians on the X line...

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0 * Math.PI;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 2 * Math.PI;
```

Comment: Yes, line will work fine.

Comment: Have you tried it? What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I can't get the units in radians on the X line, so I haven't been able to draw anything yet. I thought it had to do with my chart type, but now I've been told line works fine im kinda stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that works for me:

```
var data = new List<Tuple<double,double>>();
for (double x = 0; x < Math.PI * 2; x += Math.PI / 180.0) {
    data.Add(Tuple.Create(x, Math.Sin(x)));
}
chart1.ChartAreas.Add("area1");
var series = chart1.Series.Add("series1");
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
series.ChartArea = "area1";
series.XValueMember = "Item1";
series.YValueMembers = "Item2";
chart1.DataSource = data;
```

Result:

[image: form with chart]

Comment: Thanks alot dude, but why do you divide Math.Pi by 180?

Comment: That's pretty arbitrary, but it's 1 degree (in radians), it's just the step value I traditionally choose in these situations I guess. Feel free to change it to any value you like, it just changes the smoothness of the line.

Comment: what does XValueMembers and YValueMembers do? For some reason I can't specify my own name, or the chart will get glitchy.

Comment: They refer to the `Item1` and `Item2` properties on the `Tuple` class. I am binding (via the `DataSource` property) a list of tuples to the chart. You can bind pretty much anything, so the chart needs to know which properties of the bound objects to look at.

Comment: I thought so, but the thing that I didnt quite catch is how you know that you knew that the properties were called Item1 and Item2. Can you tell me how? Because I was staring at the tuple class documentation but I didnt read anything about Item1 or Item2. I often have a hard time finding tricks like knowing that charts can be used for data binding etc. Do you think it has to do with inexperience and this will come with time or do you think I need to do more research on the docs?

Comment: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx) is the MSDN page for the specific `Tuple<T1,T2>` class. I imagine you were looking at the general `Tuple` page. You could also pull the `Tuple.Create(..)` out into a variable in the code above, and then use intellisense to look at its properties - type a `.` after the variable and you should see the list pop up. You will get to know standard .Net idioms like databinding (look for `DataSource`/`ValueMember`/`DisplayMember` properties) with experience. Getting good at navigating the docs will help too though!